# Cannot use variable $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] in php mail()

Tags: php, email

I tested this:

```
<?php
 $to = "recipient@example.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $server = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
 $body = "From: ". $server. "<br>";
 $body .= "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

This will never send emails to me although the feedback "successfully" is displayed.
The code will work (email actually sent) however if I removed the inclusion of

```
$server = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

in the email body.

### Very weird, it doesn't make sense ?

This is just a PHP page. I call this page from a browser !! Please try ...

UPDATE!! okay, Instead of using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], I use a string "user.server.com" directly. AND, it did not work !!
But, when I modified a string a bit, like "user.server.com.us", it works !!
So basically, the mail server filler its own reference to its domain, not sure why its doing this...

Comment: The title is all wrong. `$_SERVER['HTTP_POST']` is just an *expression* that will evaluate to a value. The expression will evaluate to the same value in this case .. `mail()` or not. So then; what is the *value*? And why does this matter?

Comment: Are you running this through a browser or from the CLI?

Comment: mail() returns true if the SMTP server accepts the mail. It doesn't mean the mail was actually delivered. Check the mail server's logs to see what happens AFTER php disconnects.

Comment: Are you running this from the command line? The `$_SERVER` array is very sparsely populated if run from the command line. Also, `HTTP_HOST` does not make much sense when run from the command line, so assume it is not there.

Comment: Hi, I am not using any command line interface. Just a PHP source code, and call the page from web browser. If I try to stick the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] value in email content. No emails are sent anymore. I tested on 2 web hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Some spam servers grade your message as 'spammy' for urls in the body. Unfortunately you'll be hard-pressed to find a more specific error message with `mail()` unless you have access to the sender and recipient's mail server logs. Give SwiftMailer or another PHP Mailing library for better support.

Answer (score 0):

When using mail() function you are required to specify 'From' header. Please refer to this documentation page, look for 'additional_headers' parameter's Notes section.

So your mail() call will look like this:

`mail($to, $subject, $body, 'From: some.guy@example.com');`

Comment: The thing is the code works whether or not From is included. The problem is with the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

Comment: Then my suggestion would be to put these two lines on the very first line of your script (just after "<?"): error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors', true); and see what will pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you don't receive it because there these days all major webmails use anti spam filters and probably your message is detected as a spam.
The solution is to specify exactly your email for $from variable, if you don't specify your real email your message is detected as spam.